# Zooming with anchor point in Openlayers programatically

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am working on a tabletop application where the touch input is represented as browser touchevents.

I need a zooming function in the OL which is, alike to [ol.View.rotate](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html#rotate) and zoom with the zoom-center-point different from view-center-point. I know about the [ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom.html) which does exactly the thing. However, I cannot use it. I've already tried the sequence of:

1. translate zoom-center-point to view-center-point
2. zoom
3. translate back

but this is a bit wierd considering the fact, that the implementation already exists for `ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom`. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I used part of the code for `ol.interaction.PinchZoom`. Source: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/src/ol/interaction/pinchzoom.js